# How to integrate 3-legged OAuth system to and 2-legged OAuth system

Tags: django, oauth, integration, django-authentication, 2-legged

I have a system provide main service using user account with 2-legged OAuth. I also have another system provide service with API to call but it authenticate using 3-legged OAuth. Currently, the 2 system have independent user base. Now i want to keep the main system user base and integrate API system call to the main system, some how remove user base in API system (I mean keep it there but don't use it anymore).

User case is below:

- User register account on the main system (1)
- Another account was created automatically on the API system (2)
- Whenever main system need to get/save info (CRUD tasks) from API system, it will do the 3-legged OAuth using user info automated create in (2) to authenticate to API system and do their respective tasks. (3)

What is the option choices to implement the integration like that? I don't want to change the code base of both system, do not completely remove OAuth from either main system or API system is impossible. Both of system using Python Django framework.